# Are there any decent picture editing programs in Ubuntu like Ifran View?

Tags: software-recommendation

XnViewMP could be fine but how can I instal it? I can't understand the forums sort  of coding. I can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you like XNView then download the deb package from [here](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/#downloads). If Ubuntu software center won't let you install it then do a `sudo apt-get install gdebi` and open the `deb` file with GDebi.

Another software for image editing is Pinta. You can install it with `sudo apt-get install pinta`.

After all GIMP is the best solution, but if you do simple adjustments to images those two alternatives are good enough.

Answer (score 1):

To install XnView, first you need to know if your Ubuntu is 64bit or 32bit, then download the appropriate deb file. [This](http://download.xnview.com/XnViewMP-linux.deb) is for 32bit and [this](http://download.xnview.com/XnViewMP-linux-x64.deb) for 64bit Ubuntu.

After that, just double click the deb file from nautilus, or if you prefer using terminal, just type

```
sudo dpkg -i XnViewMP-linux.deb
```

or

```
sudo dpkg -i XnViewMP-linux-x64.deb
```

from the download directory.

Answer (score 0):

Won't [`GIMP`](http://www.gimp.org/) get your job done ?

It's also available at Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

Use **GIMP**, type in terminal

`sudo apt-get install gimp`